# MVC Create List and fill auto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I create an empty list and put all items to the list with several control
Here is the items that I want to put in the list;

```
 var memberAdminOrMajor = Db.Members
     .Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypeForReeve.BelediyeBaskani)
     .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
     .Select(m => m.Mail)
     .ToList();

 var memberBM = Db.Members
     .Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypeForReeve.SahaElemanı)
     .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
     .Select(m => m.Mail)
     .ToList();
```

I have tried something like this for getting items to dropdownlist ;

```
var list = new List<DropDownListItem>();
var MembersForDrop = Db.Members.OrderBy(o => o.Sira)
    .Where(p=>p.MemberType == (MemberTypeForReeve)2);

foreach (var temp in MembersForDrop)
{
    list.Add(new DropDownListItem() 
    { 
        Text = temp.Name + "." + temp.SurName, 
        Value = temp.Id 
    });
}
```

how Can I get `memberAdminOrMajor` and `memberBM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need both list in single view. So create a view model which contains your lists and other data:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MemberAdminOrMajors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MemberBMs { get; set; }

    public int SelectedAdmin {get; set;}
    public int SelectedBM {get; set; }

    // other data
}
```

In your action method fill the view model and pass to view:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
     var model=new MyViewModel
     {
         MemberAdminOrMajors = Db.Members
             .Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypeForReeve.BelediyeBaskani)
             .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
             .Select(m => new SelectListItem{ Text=m.Mail, Value=m.Id });

         MemberBMs= Db.Members
             .Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypeForReeve.SahaElemanı)
             .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
             .Select(m => new SelectListItem{ Text=m.Mail, Value=m.Id });

         // collectiong other data
     }
     return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model MyNamespace.MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedAdmin, Model.MemberAdminOrMajors)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedBM, Model.MemberBMs)

    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Now if you have a post back action like this you could get user selected values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResoult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    var adminId = model.SelectedAdmin;
    var bmId = model.SelectedBM;
    // rest of code
}
```

But if you want marge 2 list in 1 list you could write:

```
var newList=Db.Members
    .Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypeForReeve.BelediyeBaskani
        || m.MemberType == MemberTypeForReeve.SahaElemanı)
    .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
    .Select(m => new SelectListItem{ Text=m.Mail, Value=m.Id })
    .ToList();
```

You could also `concat` to list:

```
var newList=memberAdminOrMajor.Concat(memberBM)
    .Select(m => new SelectListItem{ Text=m.Mail, Value=m.Id });
```

Comment: but I need them in a list not as model

Comment: Could you explain more? How and where you want use them?

Comment: Okay you made a var model with myViewModel. to return it to the view. But I dont want to return that. So I want to use MemberAdminOrMajors and MemberBMs in one vat item. so I should Combine list items into 1

Comment: I have updated my post. Please check and say is this answer you question or not.

Comment: yes. I've tried this before but it didnt bring both :/ thx a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a select list; and then you are not far off.

```
        var MembersForDrop = 
            Db.Members
                .OrderBy(o => o.Sira)
                .Where(p=>p.MemberType == (MemberTypeForReeve)2)
                .Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = string.Format("{0}.{1}", m.Name, m.Surname), Value = m.Id});

        SelectList sl = new SelectList(MembersForDrop);
```